# Issue getting msgBox work in Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a little problem with Google Apps Script web app. The following script sample works perfectly in web app once its inside docs. But as a stand alone app in a browser, I keep having error messages. Please how can I make the **"Browser.msgBox (prompt)"** work in a browser?

In case you'd like to see the error message, the app can be accessed [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzCvQK8yNeZH8FPrtYwnKMgJSRI2QqEeTYdq8TB4xpb3fDmn5k/exec).

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();

var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
app.add(button);

var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
             .setId('statusLabel')
             .setVisible(false);
app.add(label);

var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
handler.addCallbackElement(label);
button.addClickHandler(handler);

return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
label.setVisible(true);

Browser.msgBox("hello world");//THIS  IS MY PROBLEM!!!

 app.close();
 return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Browser.msgBox(prompt)` will only work if the app is being shown as a dialog, such as in a Google Spreadsheet. It isn't possible to suspend the script execution in a standalone webapp.

`app.close()` isn't functional as well - you just can't close a standalone UI on the client's browser fron the server.

You can use a [PopUpPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/popup-panel) to implement the msgBox functionality in a web app, but remember that every callback starts with a fresh instance of your app.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `Browser.msgBox(prompt)` is badly named. The only place this is supported is in a container-bound script (not stand-alone web app), and only when the container is a Spreadsheet.

In the UI Service, you are running outside of the IDE/Editor - you may be interested in [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/other-examples/stock-watcher-reloaded/debug-and-test) that describes one approach to debugging in that environment.

Comment: That link is now dead.